# SwiftUI Camera Not Opening on Second App Launch

Tags: swiftui

Description: I'm developing a SwiftUI app where I want the camera to open in two cases:

When the user starts the app for the first time and has logged in.
When the user has logged in during a previous session and is re-entering the app.
I've implemented the code to open the camera when the user logs in. It works well for the first-time login, but on the second app launch, the camera does not open automatically even though the user is already logged in.

I've provided my code for reference, but I'm looking for guidance on how to make the camera open automatically in both cases.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import Photos

@main
struct YourApp: App {
    @AppStorage("isUserLoggedIn") var isUserLoggedIn: Bool = false

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(isUserLoggedIn: $isUserLoggedIn)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var isUserLoggedIn: Bool
    @State private var isCameraPresented = false
    @State private var selectedImage: Image?
    @State private var username = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    
    init(isUserLoggedIn: Binding<Bool>) {
        _isUserLoggedIn = isUserLoggedIn
        isCameraPresented = true
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
                
                // Check if the user has granted permission to access the photo library and camera
                if #available(iOS 16, *) {
                    if isUserLoggedIn {
                        // The user is logged in, show the camera
                        EmptyView()
                            .onAppear {
                                isCameraPresented = true
                            }
                    } else {
                        // Show the login form
                        VStack {
                            TextField("Username", text: $username)
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color.black)
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                            
                            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color.black)
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                            
                            Button("Login") {
                                // Check login credentials and handle successful login
                                //if username == "your_username" && password == "your_password" {
                                    isUserLoggedIn = true
                                    isCameraPresented = true
                                //}
                            }
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.green)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isCameraPresented, content: {
                ImagePicker(image: $selectedImage, sourceType: .camera)
            })
            .navigationBarTitle("foody")
        }
    }

    
    func checkPermissions() -> Bool {
        let cameraStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)
        let photoLibraryStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        
        return cameraStatus == .authorized && photoLibraryStatus == .authorized
    }
    
    func requestPermissions() {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { photoStatus in
            if photoStatus == .authorized {
                AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { response in
                    if response {
                        // Permission granted for both photo library and camera
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            isCameraPresented = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var image: Image?
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        var parent: ImagePicker
        @Binding var image: Image?
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker, image: Binding<Image?>) {
            self.parent = parent
            self._image = image
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
            if let uiImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            }
            
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
        
        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, image: $image)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.sourceType = sourceType
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
    }
}
```

I attempted to create a SwiftUI app that would automatically open the camera on two occasions: when the user initially logs in and when they return to the app after having logged in during a previous session. I expected the camera to open automatically in both cases.

On the first-time login, the code successfully opens the camera. However, on the second app launch, even though the user is logged in, the camera does not open as expected. Instead, the app opens to a black screen.

The permission is not the problem, since the first login attempt opens the camera as expected.